# Basis of $k[X_1,\ldots,X_g]$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

How many monomios exist in $k[X_1,\ldots,X_g]$ of degree d? following my calculations is $g^d$, am I right? is this a monomial basis of the polynomial ring $k[X_1,\ldots,X_g]$ of degree $d$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you take $g=d=2$, then your calculation, which you have not shown, gives that there are $4$ monomials of of degree $2$ in $k[X_1,X_2]$. This is not tue because there are only $3$ such monomials.

Comment: Remember that $X_1X_2$ and $X_2X_1$ are the same monomial of degree $2$, while your counting considers them as two different monomials.

Comment: @Arthur it's true, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I have no idea how did you get that number. If $\alpha_i$ is the degree of $X_i$ in a monominal, you want 
$$\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\ldots+\alpha_g=d$$
and each of these produces a different monomial.

This corresponds to inserting $g-1$ separators into a string of 1's of length $d$. E.g. for $g=d=3$ we have
$$1|1|1\leftrightarrow x^1y^1z^1,\quad 11|1|\leftrightarrow x^2y^1z^0,\quad ||111\leftrightarrow x^0y^0z^3,\quad\ldots$$
The length of the whole string is $d+g-1$ and we want to choose $g-1$ separators, so the answer is
$$\binom{d+g-1}{g-1}=\binom{g+d-1}d$$